# RSA with Carmichael number

Tags: rsa, number-theory

I've to prove that RSA still works with a public key $(e,pq)$ where p is a prime and q is a Carmichael number such that $q<p$ and $\gcd(e,(p-1)(q-1))=1$

I know how RSA works wiht $p,q$ primes but when $q$ is not a prime how can I prove that

$$M^{(p-1)(q-1)n}\equiv 1 \mod{pq}$$
with $n$ integer and $\gcd (M,pq)=1$.

Comment: Try using the defining property of Carmichael numbers in place of a famous theorem.

Comment: Hint: Prove $\gcd(p,q)=1$. That established, use the CRT to reduce what needs to be proved to proving it modulo $p$ and $q$. For $p$, do as usual with Fermat's Little Theorem. For $q$, use the definition of a Carmichael number.